# Trouble setting the value of a struct in reflection

Tags: go

Let's say I have a base struct that's a composite of two others:

```
type Config struct {
    common.Config
    common.ServerConfig
    APIPath      string `type:"string" name:"apipath" default:"localhost:8443" desc:"Path to the gRPC API server"`
    ServePath    string `type:"string" name:"servepath" default:"/" desc:"Path to serve the API from"`
    Organization string `type:"string" name:"organization" default:"" desc:"Default organization name"`
}
```

I'd like to iterate through every field in the struct and pull values into the struct:

```
func NewConfig(c Configer) {
    setConfigFlags(reflect.TypeOf(c).Elem(), c.GetViper())
}
```

So I'd call it so:

```
conf := Config{}
common.NewConfig(&conf)
```

My setConfigFlags is doing some recursion:

```
func setConfigFlags(t reflect.Type, viper *viper.Viper) {
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        switch field.Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            setConfigFlags(field.Type, viper)
            continue
        case reflect.String:
            fieldValue := reflect.ValueOf(&field).Elem()
            if !fieldValue.IsValid() || !fieldValue.CanSet() {
                return
            }
            fieldValue.SetString(
                viper.GetString(field.Tag.Get("name")),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Now once I hit the SetString line towards the bottom I'm getting this error:

```
panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.SetString on struct Value
```

When I look at the type of fieldValue at that point it's a structfield. I'm having trouble trying to address the value and change the value of the field. I believe I'm not grabbing the address of the actual struct field properly. The examples and documentation surely isn't helping.

In this particular example I'm pulling viper values. Basically looking for a way to define my viper definitions via struct tags, that's the ultimately goal.

Comment: `reflect.TypeOf(c).Elem()`... You're passing in the *type* of `c` not its *value*, you won't be able to set anything to a type. `reflect.Type` as the argument to your set config func is the first problem, it should be `reflect.Value` and it should be addressable.

Comment: This is so confusing lol

Comment: Apologies. You want to populate the fields of the ‘c’ value right? Well that is not possible through its type. That means that ‘reflects.Type’ is the wrong choice for the argument type to your setconfigflags function. Is that a bit more clear?

Comment: Yes, it was totally clear. I'm trying to re-adapt my example now to use reflect.Value as the param. I'm on my way :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As comments by mkopriva have noted, the code is attempting to set a value on a type.  Use a value.

```
func setConfigFlags(v reflect.Value, viper *viper.Viper) {
    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        switch field.Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            setConfigFlags(v.Field(i), viper)
            continue
        case reflect.String:
            v.Field(i).SetString(viper.GetString(field.Tag.Get("name")))
        }
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
func NewConfig(c Configer) {
    setConfigFlags(reflect.Value(c).Elem(), c.GetViper())
}
```

Comment: Your handle is perfect for responding to my question. Thanks iLoveReflection, I'll implement your changes and report back. :-)

Comment: Follow up question, how can I trigger a method named Parse on the struct? I've declared Parse on my structs and am trying to do this:

method := reflect.ValueOf(field).MethodByName("Parse") if method.Kind() != reflect.Invalid { method.Call(make([]reflect.Value, 0)) }. All the values return invalid so it's never triggered :-/

Comment: @ddibiase  You are calling reflect.ValueOf on a reflect.Value.  Use this code: `method :=field.MethodByName("Parse")`

Comment: Hmmm, what if I want to find the method outside the loop? directly against the v property? It comes in as value but if I attempt method := v.MethodByName("Parse") it returns an invalid reflect.Value :-/

Comment: I cannot intuit what code might cause the problem described in your previous comment. Ask a new question showing the code that you are using.

Comment: Good point, I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58736651/calling-struct-method-with-reflection