# Calling struct method with reflection

Tags: go, reflection

I'm having trouble calling a method in my recursive reflection function. Here it is:

```
func setPropertiesFromFlags(v reflect.Value, viper *viper.Viper) {
    t := v.Type()
    method := v.MethodByName("Parse")
    fmt.Println(method)
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        switch field.Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            setPropertiesFromFlags(v.Field(i), viper)
        case reflect.String:
            v.Field(i).SetString(viper.GetString(field.Tag.Get("name")))
    }
}
```

I'm calling the function with:

```
// Config struct passed to all services
type Config struct {
    common.Config
    common.ServerConfig
    common.AuthConfig
}
// Parse the thing already!
func (c *Config) Parse() {
    fmt.Println("RUN THIS THING")
}
int main() {
   setPropertiesFromFlags(reflect.ValueOf(c).Elem(), viper)
}
```

What I'm hoping for is to get my parse method in the place where I'm printing method and run .Call() against it. Instead it's printing out: `<invalid reflect.Value>` which I cannot call against.

I suppose I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the return values of each method. I know I have to use ValueOf to pull the value but it seems any permutation I try I'm getting the methods from the reflection class itself :-p *sigh*

Comment: I believe it's because it's declared on a pointer, the `Parse` method that is, but you are passing in a *value* to your function. That is, to fix this, declare `Parse` on a non-pointer. Or pass in the pointer, i.e. `setPropertiesFromFlags(reflect.ValueOf(c), viper)` (without `.Elem()`) and then when you need to manipulate the struct inside `setPropertiesFromFlags` call `Elem` there.

Comment: ... alternatively keep doing what you're doing but retrieve the method from v's "address", i.e. `v.Addr().MethodByName("Parse")`.

Comment: @mkopriva you beat me to the answer in these comments and your last comment is perhaps the best answer.  Should you write an actual answer instead of a comment?

Comment: @iLoveReflection i'm too lazy, your answer is good enough.

Comment: @ddibiase couple demonstrations of what you can and cannot do depending on whether you have a pointer or a value. https://play.golang.com/p/vxyIIvrsBZt (updated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the method is on the pointer receiver, but the function is working with a valuer receiver. 
Rewrite the function to work with a pointer to a struct:

```
func setPropertiesFromFlags(vp reflect.Value, viper *viper.Viper) {
    method := vp.MethodByName("Parse")
    fmt.Println(method)

    v := vp.Elem()
    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        switch field.Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.Struct:
            setPropertiesFromFlags(v.Field(i).Addr(), viper) // <-- take address of field here
        case reflect.String:
            v.Field(i).SetString(viper.GetString(field.Tag.Get("name")))
        }
    }
}
```

Call like this:

```
   setPropertiesFromFlags(reflect.ValueOf(c), viper) // <-- do not call Elem()
```

Comment: I see now. I wasn't passing in .Addr() THAT was the major issue. Thanks gents.